# Compensate Temperature with pressure sensor?

Tags: instrumentation

I'm using this pressure sensor and when I submerse the pipe inside the liquid the pressure should be held constant ,but due to the temperature the sensor keeps giving different values after certain time.How can I compensate for this ,Mathematically and programmatically  ?

Comment: 'this pressure sensor'? I think you need to actually tell us what pressure sensor it is. What fluid?, what temperature? Engineers can't pull solutions out of thin air.

Comment: its an air pressure sensor( MPS20N0040D-S ), 0-40kpa working range , temperature range is -40 to 85 operating range .

Comment: Read its datasheet. Multiply its temperature dependence by the temperature variation, and see if that is consistent with your observed variance in output values. If they aren't consistent, find out what else is causing variance before compensating for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

Only your OEM sensor supplier can tell you with the vague question so far. Temp. Comp. matters!

https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=Temp_Compensation_MEAS_Pressure_Sensors&DocType=SS&DocLang=EN